# Django url tag adds filepath

Tags: django, django-templates

In urls.py, I defined as,

url(r'^'+settings.URL_PREFIX+r'$', 'myapp.project.views.index', name="homepage"),

in settings.py, I defined URL_PREFIX as,

URL_PREFIX = 'myapp/'

and in template, I used url tag in an anchor as,

{% url homepage %}

Link becomes:

http://localhost/home/muluturk/web/myapp/myapp/ instead of http://localhost/myapp/. It adds /home/muluturk/web/myapp/ whis is the directory of project. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It caused by apache config file:

PythonOption django.root /home/muluturk/web/myapp

Removing /home/muluturk/web/myapp from this line solved my problem