# Django url template tags adding absolute filepath

Tags: python, django, apache, passenger, wsgi

I am having a problem where my {% url %} django template tag is adding the filepath to the web address in production.  This is not replicated on my local development machine.

With urls.py setup such that:

```
url("^about_us/$", views.about_us, name="about_us"),
```

In production, I am getting the link
www.mysite.com/home/username/myapp/about_us
instead of
www.mysite.com/about_us

I have looked at this similar issue and it does not help with my specific application:
[Django url tag adds filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469988/django-url-tag-adds-filepath)

My django project is hosted on A2 (shared) hosting using apache, wsgi, and passenger.  My .htaccess file look the following:

```
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN 
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/myapp"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/user/virtualenv/myapp/2.7/bin/python2.7"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
```

My passenger_wsgi.py file looks like the following:

```
import myapp.wsgi
SCRIPT_NAME = '/home/user/myapp'

class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    """
    Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI because Passenger doesn't provide it.
    """
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urlparse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

application = myapp.wsgi.application
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

I feel like something is off in one of these files.  How can I get remove the /home/user/myapp from my links?

**Update**:  I thought I figured out this problem.  When I change the SCRIPT_NAME variable in passenger_wsgi.py to

```
SCRIPT_NAME = '.'
```

This initially fixes the problem when I go to the home page.  However, a new problem results in that if you go to www.mysite.com/about_us, then the {% url %} tag will result in

www.mysite.com/about_us/about_us

Maybe this will provide some direction to the solution.

**Update #2**:  I did find this:
https://smartlazycoding.com/django-tutorial/deploy-a-django-website-to-a2-hosting

From this website, changing the passenger_wsgi.py file to

```
import os
import sys
# set variables
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
#setup django application
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

fixes the issue, but then you still have the POST issue it describes.  I then made the changes the website recommends:

```
import os
import sys
# Set up paths and environment variables
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project_name.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME
        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

This results back into my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer that appears to work for now.  The solution is basically the original passenger_wsgi.py file posted above, but setting SCRIPT_NAME equal to an empty string.  My passenger_wsgi.py file looks like the following:

```
import myapp.wsgi
#SCRIPT_NAME = '/home/user/myapp'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''

class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    """
    Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI because Passenger doesn't provide it.
    """
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

application = myapp.wsgi.application
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

This fixes my path issue and I am able to use POST.  I don't know if there are any caveats of setting SCRIPT_NAME = '' over the app's root path, but if anyone knows of any issues of doing this, please share.